# More Pythonic Way to Convert 24 bit ints to 32 bit ints

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion

I currently use the following code to convert an array of bytes which represent little endian signed 24 bit integers into a list of signed 32 bit integers.

```
xs = list(bytes_object)
ys = [xs[x:x+3] + [255] if xs[x+2] & 128 else xs[x:x+3] + [0]
      for x in range(0, len(xs), 3)]
int32s = [struct.unpack('<i', bytes(y))[0] for y in ys]
```

Is there a more pythonic or efficient way to handle the conversion?

Comment: It's obviously more efficient to skip the work of unpacking and repacking the bytes and just insert a new 0 or 0xFF byte every 4 bytes. The most pythonic way to do that may or may not actually be the most efficient, so… which one do you want?

Comment: … but it looks like you want to not just convert them into 32-bit ints, but also unpack them into Python `int` objects. Are you going to use the 32-bit ints after that? If not, why not just skip building and unpacking the list of 32-bit ints in the first place? Alternatively, if you do need them, have you considering using an `array` or `numpy` array of int32s instead of making a list of ints?

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer that describes the most pythonic way and another answer which describes the most efficient way.

Comment: OK, what is the actual result you want here? (a) a list of Python ints, (b) a list of Python ints and a list of packed int32s, (c) just something that acts like an array of ints

Comment: @abanert The int32 list get converted into a numpy array of float64 values.

Comment: OK, so if we build a numpy array of int32 values, that should be even better, because you can do an array-wide cast, right?

Comment: @abarnet yeah thats what happens in the parts of my code that I haven't uploaded

Comment: so is it then more efficient then to convert my array of bytes to a list, insert 0x00 or 0xFF every four elements, convert back to an array of bytes, and then use numpy.fromstring()?

Comment: Converting *"little endian signed 24 bit integers into a list of signed 32 bit integers"* is not pythonic, so no. Just do whatever ugly thing you have to do for this job.

Comment: @user7147804 Probably, but it's probably even more efficient to just use a `np.view` directly on those bytes. I can't remember the exact details, but see my answer, and if you get stuck (or if I get home and try it myself and get embarrassed by whatever stupid mistake I made), I can probably fix it.

Comment: What input do you have, and what is your expected output, *exactly*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is right. I'm _pretty sure you want to turn, e.g., `b'\x01\x00\x00\xff\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` into `[1, -2, 0, 0]`, but it would be nice to know that I've guessed right.

Answer (score 3):

Of the top of my head, something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# First convert the buffer to an array of 3-vectors of uint8s
a3 = np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 3)

# Now sign-extend it to an array of 4-vectors of uint8s
signs = (a3[..., 0] > 0x80) * 0xFF
a4 = np.concatenate((signs.reshape(-1, 1), a), axis=1)

# Now convert that to an array of int32s
i = a4.view(np.int32)

# And what you eventually wanted to do was convert to float64?
f = i.astype(np.float64)
```

I'm sure I've made at least one mistake (surely this won't work on a big-endian system, at least), and I don't have a computer with numpy installed in front of me, but hopefully that gets you started. No need to do anything in a Python loop.

Comment: Note for myself for later: read the `view` docs carefully; verify that the striding is guaranteed to be correct, figure out where to bitflip if native `int32` is big-endian, find the one extra `reshape` you always seem to include everywhere, then you can look for actual bugs/improvements.

Comment: `signs = (a3[..., 0] > 0x80) * 0xFF` I think prematurely converts to int32.

Answer (score 2):

outside of numpy, this is pretty pythonic:

```
bytes_object = b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0'
[int.from_bytes(bytes_object[x:x+3], byteorder='little', signed=True) for x in range(0, len(bytes_object), 3)]
```

Comment: This is super slow, but it gives me a starting point to verify my data integrity and understand other solutions that use weird strides to cover large arrays of such data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solutions. `-8388608` -> `FF80 0000`(32bit) or `FFFF FFFF FF80 0000`(64bit) does the magic to convert the signed values.

```
test_bytes = b'\x58\x18\x85'
def byte3toint(tmp, signed=True):
    b = tmp[0] | tmp[1] << 8 | tmp[2] << 16 # restore the bit represention
    if signed and tmp[2] & 128:
        b |= -8388608
    return b
assert byte3toint(test_bytes) == int.from_bytes(test_bytes, 'little', signed=True)
```